# SQL finding rows that only contain chars from a certain Unicode range

Tags: sql, sql-server, unicode

I recently asked a question to obtain rows that contain characters in a certain Unicode range.

```
SELECT *
FROM #kanjinames
WHERE UNICODE(LEFT(ForeNames, 1)) BETWEEN 0x4e00 AND 0x9fff
```

A very helpful user shared the above with me. To my understanding it checks the first character on the left and if it is within the Unicode range it returns an a the row. Through testing I believe this works.

My current problem is how do I go about checking the entire column is within the range? For example:

```
石山コンタクトレンズ
```

The above contains characters outside of the range (the first two characters are within range) in the query above but I am not sure about how I go about checking the entire field. I am away of using stuff like

```
is not like N'%^a-z%'
```

for the English alphabet. Just not sure how to apply it for this situation.

Any help would be great on this.

Comment: Does SSMS not allow you to enter Japanese characters into a Unicode `N` like expression?  By the way, does your database use a collation which support Unicode?

Comment: It is using a Latin1_General_CI_AS Collation. It does let me use Japanese characters.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will work:

```
SELECT *
FROM #kanjinames
WHERE ForeNames NOT LIKE '%[^' + NCHAR(0x4e00) + '-' NCHAR(0x9fff) + ']%';
```

That is, the string contains no characters outside that sequence.

Edit: I had to alter this slightly to get it to work. I had to use the decimal values instead of the hex.

```
SELECT *
    FROM #kanjinames
    WHERE ForeNames NOT LIKE '%[^' + NCHAR(19968) + '-' + NCHAR(40802) + ']%';
```

This still returns blank values but I removed those separately.

Comment: I had to alter this slightly to get it to work. I had to use the decimal values instead of the hex.

SELECT *
    FROM #kanjinames
    WHERE ForeNames NOT LIKE '%[^' + NCHAR(19968) + '-' + NCHAR(40802) + ']%';
This still returns blank values but I removed those separately.

Comment: @JimmyPop13 . . . That is interesting.  I would have expected the hex values to work.

Comment: Hi Gordon, on checking the output for this it returns any row that contains a character within the range. Is there a way to return rows that only contain characters within the range? Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: @JimmyPop13 . . . The `not like '[^. . .]'` should be doing that.

Comment: You are right, I've tested it versus English letters and it works fine. Must be some issue with the Unicode ranges or something. Not sure why it is getting confused selecting Unicode. Will have to investigate further. I will be sure to add it here if I come up with an answer.